# Funny CSV format help

Tags: parsing, vbscript, csv

I've been given a large file with a funny CSV format to parse into a database.

The separator character is a semicolon (`;`). If one of the fields contains a semicolon it is "escaped" by wrapping it in doublequotes, like this `";"`.

I have been assured that there will never be two adjacent fields with trailing/ leading doublequotes, so this format should technically be ok.

Now, for parsing it in VBScript I was thinking of

1. Replacing each instance of `";"` with a GUID,
2. Splitting the line into an array by semicolon,
3. Running back through the array, replacing the GUIDs with `";"`

It seems to be the quickest way. Is there a better way? I guess I could use substrings but this method seems to be acceptable...

Comment: Do you intend storing this information in your database?

Comment: Yes - that's where the data is headed.

Comment: I would point out, not for the first time, that the C in CSV stands for "comma" - if your separator is not a comma, you don't have CSV data.

Comment: What happens if a data field contains a `"` character???

Comment: If you use one of the text handlers (OLEDB Jet Text or the ODBC Text Desktop Driver) this can probably be handled easily by using a schema.ini file.  BTW, I believe in locales where comma is the decimal point a CSV file uses semicolon as the field delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method sounds fine with the caveat that there's absolutely *no* possibility that your GUID will occur in the text itself.

On approach I've used for this type of data before is to just split on the semi-colons regardless then, if two adjacent fields end and start with a quote, combine them.

For example:

```
Pax;is;a;good;guy";" so;says;his;wife.
```

becomes:

```
0 Pax
1 is
2 a
3 good
4 guy"
5 " so
6 says
7 his
8 wife.
```

Then, when you discover that fields 4 and 5 end and start (respectively) with a quote, you combine them by replacing the field 4 closing quote with a semicolon and removing the field 5 opening quote (and joining them of course).

```
0 Pax
1 is
2 a
3 good
4 guy; so
5 says
6 his
7 wife.
```

Comment: I imagine half the world's software is based on non-duplication of GUIDs. Plus, the fields are not intended for GUIDs so every-day non-experimental/malicious behaviour will not result in GUIDs being entered.

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo-code, given:

- *input*: A string, first character is *input*[0]; last
  character is *input*[*length*]. Further, assume one dummy
  character, *input*[*length*+1]. It can be anything except
  `;` and `"`. This string is one line of the "CSV" file.
- *length*: positive integer, number of characters in *input*

Do this:

- set *start* = 0
- if *input*[0] = `';'`:

  - you have a blank field in the beginning; do whatever with it
  - set start = 2
- endif
- for each *c* between 1 and *length*:

  - next iteration unless *string*[*c*] = `';'`
  - if input[c-1] ≠ `'"'` or input[c+1] ≠ `'"'`:                     **// test for escape sequence `";"`**

    - found field consting of half-open range [start,c); do whatever
      with it. Note that in the case of empty fields, start≥c, leaving
      an empty range
    - set start = c+1
  - endif
- end foreach

Untested, of course. Debugging code like this is always fun….

The special case of *input*[0] is to make sure we don't ever look at *input[-1]*. If you can make *input[-1]* safe, then you can get rid of that special case. You can also put a dummy character in *input*[0] and then start your data—and your parsing—from *input*[1].

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to find instances of the regex:

> `[^"];[^"]`

and then break the string apart with substring:

```
List<string> ret = new List<string>();
Regex r = new Regex(@"[^""];[^""]"); 
Match m;

while((m = r.Match(line)).Success)
{
    ret.Add(line.Substring(0,m.Index + 1);
    line = line.Substring(m.Index + 2);
}
```

(Sorry about the C#, I don't known VBScript)

Answer (score 0):

Using quotes is normal for .csv files.  If you have quotes in the field then you may see opening and closing and the embedded quote all strung together two or three in a row.

Comment: Yes, but the standard for CSV is to wrap the *whole* field in quotes if that field contains the separator character. Escaping the character like that is non-standard and I'm hoping my parsing method will be enough to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server you could try using T-SQL to handle everything for you.

```
SELECT * INTO MyTable FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Data Source=F:\MyDirectory;Extended Properties="text;HDR=No"')...
[MyCsvFile#csv]
```

That will create and populate "MyTable". Read more on this subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213657/how-to-read-csv-files-line-by-line-in-vbscript) on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using RegEx to break up the strings.

- Find every ';' that is not a part of
  ";" and change it to something else
  that does not appear in your fields.
- Then go through and replace ";" with ;

Now you have your fields with the correct data.

Most importers can swap out separator characters pretty easily.

This is basically your GUID idea. Just make sure the GUID is unique to your file before you start and you will be fine. I tend to start using 'Z'. After enough 'Z's, you will be unique (sometimes as few as 1-3 will do).

Jacob