# SQL how to select column by index instead of name from csv

Tags: sql, vba, csv, oledb, adodb

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & ";" & _
                "Extended Properties='Text;HDR=No'"

sql = "SELECT Col1 FROM abc.csv"
rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

how can I select Col1 by column number while there is no column title row from a csv file using vba?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to approach the read differently, but this solution would work for you.

[Link to StackOverflow Q/A that will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747105/specify-target-columns-on-import-csv-to-access)

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM abc.csv"
rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
var column1 = "";

Do While Not rsCSV.EOF
    column1 = rs.Fields(0)
    'Do something with the column1 data
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: thank you, but what is [SO Article]? how can I actually write the query? I tried use [SO Article][1] to take place Col1, but failed.

Comment: Sorry, the link didn't work correctly.  I edited the link and provide some sample code.